# VS 2012 does not let me choose any framework

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I have this strange issue : When trying creating new Visual Studio 2012 projet, I can't choose any version of the .Net Framework in the new projet popup window.

All this on Windows 8 up to date. With VS2012 Ultimate Update 2

Tried to repair Visual Studio but got the following error :

> MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (vs_professionalcore) failed: Error Message Id: 1303 ErrorMessage: Error 1303.**The installer has insufficient privileges to access this directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Help Viewer\v2.0.  The installation cannot continue.  Log on as administrator or contact your system administrator.**
>   [0EF0:03CC][2013-06-07T14:15:27]: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (vs_professionalcore) failed: Error Message Id: 1712 ErrorMessage: Error 1712.One or more of the files required to restore your computer to its previous state could not be found.  Restoration will not be possible.

Though I ran the setup through the "Run as administrator" shortcut.

Any idea?

Comment: What type of project are you trying to create? What versions of the framework do you actually have installed? Which version do you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio can be temperamental when installing upgrades, etc

Firstly, checking fundamentals ( although I doubt this is your problem).

Are you using the computer as a user with Administrative rights? I suspect you are, but if not, you need to have administrative rights.

Have you checked if any files are being blocked by your firewall? When I switched to the full version of Avast I find I have to disable the File System Shield It loves to remove my executable files when I try to run my visual studio projects.

I had problems when upgrading to VS2012 Professional. (SDK, .Net, Visual C++ Redistributable package)

**ENSURE ALL OF THESE ARE COMPATIBLE WITH THE CURRENT VERSION OF VS YOU ARE USING**

What I did, was I ended up uninstalling EVERYTHING that was associated with both Visual Studio downloads. If you are able to remove and save your project files elsewhere and then bring them back. Go through all your program files to see if there is anything hidden in the wrong folder and check your C drive.

Which meant downloading and reinstalling (fresh):

I think if you clean out your program files, it should be ok. I wouldn't recommend going into your register unless you are very sure of what you are doing. IF you have already made changes to the register then we'll have a look at that and other options (if this doesn't solve your problem).

TIP For EVERY project I write I copy and paste into a text file (in notepad plus) and then email it to myself - the formdesigner, form and any modules, classes etc. I do this for ALL my programs in ALL languages. That way if there is a problem with the software or my pc I can recreate the projects without too much ado.

Comment: Thank your for you reply Yvette. You made me remember something. When I first run the install, I did not use the "Run as administrator" which led to errors...though I used the command to "Repair". So after I clean reinstall it works Now.